# Swift - 'attempt to insert row 1 into section 0, but there are only 0 rows in section 0 after the update"

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Помогите разобраться с вставкой ячейки в первую строчку.У меня Сервер Parse, я создал функцию по свежему уроку.У меня есть сегмент который делиться на три массива. Написал с одним массивом.Конечно же функцию установил в override func viewDidLoad().Вот мой код:

```
func insertNewMatch() {
        tableView.beginUpdates()

        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: tennisString.count+1, section: 0)

        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Очевидно что вставка по индексу которого нет.

Сначала нужно добавить данные для того чтоб было что отображать в таблице и затем обновить, только с правильным индексом.

Comment: Немного Вас не понял?  я в функции неправильно очередность функций сделал

Answer (score 0):

Эта ошибка означает что после обновления, таблица содержит 0 рядов в 0 секции, в то время как вы вставили 1 их должно было стать 1.
Это происходит из за того что вы не обновили источник данных для таблицы во время вставки. Таблица получает количество рядов в методе

```
tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
```

В вашем случае, если `numberOfRows` это `tennisString.count`, то в методе `insertTennisMatch` нужно сделать следующее:

```
tennisString.append(newMatch) // Добавление нового матча в источник данных
```

перед `tableView.endUpdates()`

Таким образом `numberOfRows` будет соответствовать `tennisString.count` после обновления

Comment: не понял не много, где Ты написал newMatch мне нужно написать вместо него tennisString.count

Comment: Если tennisString это массив который содержит теннисные данные для tableView, то его нужно обновлять при вставке новых элементов